# Factorization of quasi-isomorphism is also a quasi-isomorphism

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category, $ X_\bullet
 \overset{f}{\hookrightarrow} Y_\bullet \overset{g}{\hookrightarrow} Z_\bullet$ be in $Ch(\mathcal{A})$ such that $gf:X_\bullet \hookrightarrow Z_\bullet$ is a quasi-isomorphism.
I want to show that in that case $g$ is also a quasi isomorphism. Of course its homology is epic. I tried to lift its kernel to $X_\bullet$ in order to get the obvious conclusion of this - a trivial kernel, but I couldn't do so. I tried to take define an inverse, but couldn't prove anything about it whatsoever. I remember that I did prove it in the past by lifting, and even mentioned that it is not that hard, but now im questioning whether it's even true (or maybe I'm missing something right now). I'll be glad for some help. I don't mind assuming that $\mathcal{A}=Ab$ or some other nice concrete abelian category.

Comment: What if $X,Y,Z$ are all complexes with null differential, though?

Comment: Then we get $X\overset{fg} {\overset{\sim}{=} Z}$ (pointwise), so $g$ is epic (pointwise), which means by balanceness of abelian categories its an isomorphism (since its also monic by hypothesis)

Comment: Oops, I hadn’t realized that $f$ and $g$ were monic on the complexes…

Comment: Wait, that result looks very suspicious, actually – if $X=0$ and $Z$ is any exact complex, it would mean that any sub-complex of $Z$ is exact. It doesn’t look to be the case.

Comment: You are right. So I did have a mistake last time! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Mindlack Can you make that into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I’m turning my comment into an answer. Take $X=0$ and $Z$ as any exact complex. The statement implies that any subcomplex $Y \subset Z$ is exact. This is false: consider $0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$ as $Z$ and $0 \rightarrow 2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$ as a subcomplex.